# Variable in backtick statement

Tags: sh

I've got this issue I can't get my head around.

```
FILE_PROPERTIES="info.txt"

echo `grep "ENVOI_MAIL=" ${FILE_PROPERTIES} | cut -d "=" -f "2"`
```

My FILE_PROPERTIES in the second line does not change like I would expect it to, and finishes in a file not find exception.
Would any one know why that is?

Or, in a more general manner, how would one go about calling a variable in a `` statement, so that it gets converted for output? I've tried without the {}, without any luck.

Comment: What environment is this?  The "batch" tag is for Windows batch files, but this doesn't look like Windows batch syntax.

Comment: Works here (bash 4.1.10). Probably dependent on the shell type and possibly version. Does `export FILE_PROPERTIES="info.txt"` work?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I am currently running it with sh-3.2. Will look into updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing it should work.  For example, the following should (attempt to) access both `info.txt` and `something_else.txt`.  Note that the two `echo` commands are identical.

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE_PROPERTIES="info.txt"
echo `grep "ENVOI_MAIL=" ${FILE_PROPERTIES} | cut -d "=" -f "2"`

FILE_PROPERTIES="something_else.txt"
echo `grep "ENVOI_MAIL=" ${FILE_PROPERTIES} | cut -d "=" -f "2"`
```

One possible problem is that if the file name contains spaces, it will appear to the `grep` command as two arguments.  You can avoid that by using quotation marks (not a bad idea anyway).  (The braces aren't required in this case, but there's also not a bad idea.)

```
echo `grep "ENVOI_MAIL=" "${FILE_PROPERTIES}" | cut -d "=" -f "2"`
```

Also, most modern shells support a `$(...)` syntax which is a bit nicer than the backtick form (for one thing, it can be nested):

```
echo $(grep "ENVOI_MAIL=" "${FILE_PROPERTIES}" | cut -d "=" -f "2")
```

Finally, the `echo` probably isn't necessary unless you actually need `echo`'s treatment of white space.  You might try this instead:

```
grep "ENVOI_MAIL=" "${FILE_PROPERTIES}" | cut -d "=" -f "2"
```

(I haven't tested all these commands, so watch out for typos.)

Comment: Thanks for this clear, exhaustive and informative answer! Helped me understand well what is going on. Works now well now under batch 0403-010.